# How to access Appication objects from Sync Adapter

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am working on an IM application with open fire server. I'm implementing Sync Adapter for managing the contacts.

From my sync adapter's `onPerformSync()` if I access the connection object which I kept in my Application class it returns *null*.

What am I doing wrong? How should I do that?

My Application class

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private Connection connection;
    private static MyApp instance;
    public static MyApp getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public static void setInstance(MyApp instance) {
    MyApp.instance = instance;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = new MyApp();
}
public Connection getAuthenticatedConnection() throws NullPointerException {

    if (instance.connection != null
            && instance.connection.isAuthenticated()) {
        return instance.connection;
    } else {

//  Calling service which will create connection and update the object

        Intent intent = new Intent(IM_Service_IntentMessaging.ACTION);
        intent = new Intent(getContext(), IM_Service_IntentMessaging.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("key", IM_Service_IntentMessaging.KEY_CONNECTION);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        this.context.startService(intent);

        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
//service calls this method to update the object
public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
    instance.connection = connection;
}
}
```

And my onPerformSync method is as follows...

```
@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle bundle, String authority,
        ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

    try {

        this.connection = MyApp.getInstance()
                .getAuthenticatedConnection();

        this.roster = this.connection.getRoster();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    //this line executes always
        Log.e(TAG, "connection null...ending....");

        return;
    }

    this.mAccount = account;

    Log.d(TAG, "...onPerformSync...");

    getAllContacts();
}
```

When I tried with creating break point in Application's `getAuthenticatedConnection()` method it didn't get triggered but the service `IM_Service_IntentMessaging` which i called from there to create connection is working.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem is i should remove the `android:process=":sync"` from the sync adapter's manifest file declaration. Because of that it treats like different process.